# How to extract a specific "word" from a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
dict_df = {'code': {0: 'a02',
  1: 'a03',
  2: 'a04',
  3: 'a05',
  4: 'a06',
  5: 'a07',
  6: 'a08',
  7: 'a09',
  8: 'a10'},
 'name': {0: 'Dr Mike',
  1: ' Dr.  Benjamin',
  2: 'Doctor Dre',
  3: 'ApotekOne',
  4: 'Aptek Two',
  5: 'Apotek 3',
  6: 'DrVladrimir',
  7: ' dR Sarah inc.',
  8: 'DR.John'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

I'm trying to extract in another column different strings. I will take "dr" as example but it is applies to all of them.
For "dr" I need it in any form or shape (**dr, DR, Dr, dR**) plus

- before (dr) can be blank or any other char except a letter or a number (ex.  **Dr**)
- after (dr) can be blank, point or any other char except a letter of a number (ex. **DR.John**)
- if there is no special char after (dr) (ex. blank, point, etc) and it is an uppercase letter, it is a match (ex **"Dre"** is not a match but **"DrVlad"** is a match)

What I did by now but it doesn't cover all conditions above:

```
df['inclusions']= df['name'].str.findall(r'(?i)dr|doctor|apotek|aptek|two').str.join(", ").str.lower()
```

If on the column "inclusions" I have double (dr), how can I keep only one (no duplicates)?

Thank you.

Comment: Specifically for `Doctor` or `Dr` you can use `df.name.str.findall(r'(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])d(?:r|octor)(?![a-zA-Z0-0])', flags=re.IGNORECASE).apply(bool)`. This is a negative-look-around that ensures no letters or numbers are immediately next to the keyword. It ignores case and is converted to boolean values. You can ignore the applying bool which will returns the lists of the matches instead.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by having `double dr`.

Comment: Something like "Dr. Mike dr" -> dr dr

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use an anchor to the start, a partial case insensitive group and a negative match:

```
df['inclusions']= (df['name']
                  .str.findall(r'^\s*(?i:dr|doctor|apotek|aptek|two)(?![a-z])')
                  .str.join(", ")
                  .str.lower()
                  )
```

output:

```
  code            name inclusions
0  a02         Dr Mike         dr
1  a03   Dr.  Benjamin         dr
2  a04      Doctor Dre     doctor
3  a05       ApotekOne     apotek
4  a06       Aptek Two      aptek
5  a07        Apotek 3     apotek
6  a08     DrVladrimir         dr
7  a09   dR Sarah inc.         dr
8  a10         DR.John         dr
```